# SailsJS blueprint GET model with no limit

Tags: mongodb, orm, sails.js, waterline, apiblueprint

I have a problem.
I need to use GET blueprints and I would like to receive all (without a limit) of my Models objects (think in one Model called Student). So, to do that I added in sails.config.blueprints the attribute parseBlueprintOptions and set queryOptions.criteria.limit to MaxInteger (I saw that in this URL: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-blueprints#?using-parseblueprintoptions).
But when I go to a production environment I received the next message:

> Warning: Attempting to populate 'grupos' with the specified
>   subcriteria, but this MAY NOT BE SAFE, depending on the number of
>   records stored in your models. Since this association does not support
>   optimized populates (i.e. it spans multiple datastores, or uses an
>   adapter that does not support native joins), it is not a good idea to
>   populate it along with a subcriteria that uses 'limit', 'skip', and/or
>   'sort'-- at least not in a production environment.
>
> This is because, to satisfy the specified 'limit'/'skip'/'sort', many
>   additional records may need to be fetched along the way -- perhaps
>   enough of them to overflow RAM on your server.
>
> If you are just using sails-disk during development, or are certain
>   this is not a problem based on your application's requirements, then
>   you can safely ignore this message. But otherwise, to overcome this,
>   either (A) remove or change this subcriteria and approach this query a
>   different way (such as multiple separate queries or a native query),
>   or (B) configure all involved models to use the same datastore, and/or
>   switch to an adapter like sails-mysql or sails-postgresql that
>   supports native joins.  [?] See https://sailsjs.com/support for help.

What can I do? I'd like to ignore this message or solved it but I don't know how.

NOTE: *I'm using Sails v1.0.1.*

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version of Sails: v1.0.2.

Further reading on the latest features / info of Sails Blueprint GET can be found here: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/find-where